# How a device changes window transparency?

Tags: visible-light

I visited the children's museum in Manhattan, NY.

There is a pick-a-boo device game in there. Once you touch it with your hand, it makes a window to be transparent.

What is the physics behind this?

https://youtube.com/shorts/ys1ldSS8AjA?feature=share

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to make glass nontransparent.

One way is to apply a thin film of a liquid *nematic crystal* sandwiched between two electrically conductive and transparent sheets to the surface of the glass. The molecules of the "liquid crystal" have the property of polarizing a beam of light that shines through them. Then when you apply a small voltage to the sheets, that stuff between them aligns itself with the electric field between the sheets and only passes the polarization of light that aligns with the molecules.

Then you place a polarizing filter in front of the whole shebang and align its polarization direction at 90 degrees to that of the liquid crystal when the voltage is "on". Light shines through the whole thing with the voltage off and is mostly blocked when the voltage is on. This is how the so-called *liquid crystal display* works.

If you apply another thin conductive electrode to the outer surface of the LCD and wire it up to a sensitive amplifier, you can alter the output of the amplifier by touching your fingertip against the outer electrode- and use that signal to turn the LCD on and off. This is how *touchscreens* work on laptop computers.

The other way is to mix in with the glass a chemical substance that turns dark when ultraviolet light strikes it, and turns light again when you shade it from UV light. this is how self-darkening sunglasses work.